# How do you remove a site from Sharepoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I would like to use Sharepoint Designer 2007 as an html editor. I have a web site with a lot of files in a folder on my hard drive. I do not want Sharepoint Designer to make a web site out of this. I just want to use Sharepoint Designer to edit the html files, locally.

If I ever make a mistake and click on a tool for Sites, such as summary or report, Sharepoint Designer will decide that my folder is now a web site. From that point on, Sharepoint Designer is painfully slow whenever I open a file contained in the folder that Sharepoint decided is my web site, instead of being instantaneous like it was before.

I can resolve this situation by renaming the folder containing my web site -- everything gets fast again. I can also fix it by uninstalling and reinstalling Sharepoint Designer. Neither of these is a good solution. Is there a place in Sharepoint Designer, or in application data or the registry that I can kill off the Sharepoint Designer web site that's associated with a folder on my hard drive?

Comment: Why do you want to use SharePoint Designer as your html editor?  There are so many other free html editors that you could use that wouldn't cause the issues you're experiencing with SharePoint Designer.

Comment: It has a few features that save a lot of time in my case. I will probably go with Dreamweaver or Visual Studio if I can't get this fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain this will fix your issues (as I can't easily recreate the situation you describe). But I do know where SharePoint Designer tucks away metadata about the websites you open and edit.

The next time SPD converts your folder to a web, shut down SPD and delete the contents of  the following folders:

**WebsiteCache:**
**XP:** `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\WebsiteCache`
**Vista/7:** `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache`

There is one file in WebsiteCache you may wish to keep, which is *Websites.xml*. This contains the "shortcuts" you see when you go to `File > Open Site...`

**Web Server Extensions:**
**XP:** `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache`
**Vista/7:** `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache`

Whenever SPD gets wonky about reporting which files are checked out/in, really slow to open, or just generally weird, we clean out these folders and things return to "normal".

Hope this helps!

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I did have to erase the websitecache twice, though, because the first time I opened SPD it replaced everything. I consider that very rude behavior.

Comment: Yeah, lots of rude behavior. My favorite is the occasional insertion of additional HTML code in my page layout files, which break everything until I track it down and manually remove it. Thanks, SPD! :-/